# Do I need to let ravioli made with fresh dough dry?

Tags: pasta, ravioli

I'm discovering the universe of fresh pasta, and I saw that many people let the pasta dry. Does that apply to raviolis too?

Comment: You don't need to ... but it's much more important for fresh pasta (vs. dried) to make sure the water is at a rolling boil before you put it in.  (so it cooks before it turns into paste)

Answer (score 3):

Counter-question: Do you think it’s a safe practice to let a filling that may contain raw meat or dairy hang around at room temperature or possibly even warmer for hours?

So no, you shouldn’t let homemade ravioli dry. Attempting to, even if you used a filling that is safe at room temperature, takes way longer than plain (and thin!) regular pasta. Commercial ravioli products are either quick-dried and sealed to make them shelf stable, or sold in the refrigerated section of your supermarket.

If you can’t cook and serve your ravioli immediately, either refrigerate them for short-term storage or freeze them.

And there’s no need to let plain pasta dry before cooking, one of the special charms of making fresh pasta is that it’s *fresh*, i.e. not dried. Drying is done for long-term storage. It allows working with larger batches (messing up the kitchen only once...) and having the pasta at hand without kneading, resting and rolling.

Comment: Freezing immediately after making (if not cooking immediately) makes it much easier to handle, especially as you are learning, because it is easy to err on the side of the dough being too sticky.  It can be cooked from frozen.

Comment: You know they could dry in the fridge, right?  Drying doesn't automatically mean "leave it out on the counter at room temperature".

Comment: @Joe yes, but it’s a bit complicated.

Comment: @Joe What are the benefits of letting the pasta dry? I don't use any meat in my preparations, just cheese.

Comment: @aragaoalana : the main advantage is being able to pack it up to freeze it without it all sticking together.  But even if you're not freezing it, it's useful to be able to separate the assembly of the food and the actual cooking of it, so if you're having guests over you're not trying to rush to get everything done.  So the drying is more a side-effect than the main intent.

Answer (score 0):

I just made some homemade ravioli filled with egg, ricotta and parm. Unless we were eating them that day, we would spread them out on a sheet that was dusted with cornmeal. We would let them dry on one side and then flip them over to dry on the other.I think sometimes this happened overnight. Like the poster says, you won't die from eating dried filled pasta. Trust that Italians have been doing this for centuries. They don't refrigerate their eggs either and no one dies. This country is way too obsessive about expiration dates, etc.

Answer (score -2):

I have let them dry for. 24 hours at room temp. While they have raw ground beef inside and cheese, it doesn’t matter as long as they completely dry out. Not moisture, no bacteria. I know people will protest, but that’s how my family made them for one hundred years and nobody ever got sick. Just remember to thoroughly squeeze out as much moisture from the ingredients as possible.

Comment: Do you really think 24 hours at room temperature is sufficient to completely dry ground beef? Try leaving some meat on the counter for a day and see if it completely dries out. (And that wasn't even protected in a layer of pasta!) Besides which, the issue is not just whether the things are *eventually* dry enough to inhibit bacterial growth, but also whether they're left in the danger zone for long enough for bacterial toxins to build up.

Comment: The “nobody ever got sick” claim is highly unlikely. Food poisoning can manifest as late as days after a meal.